Proof that limit of a function converges to $0$ given that some conditions hold
Define the following error metric with $L>0$ being a known constant:
$$ q(t) = d(t) - L $$
where $d(t)$ denotes the euclidean distance between two points $1$ and $2$ and is defined as follows:
$$ d(t) = \sqrt{(x_1(t) - x_2(t))^2 + (y_1(t) - y_2(t))^2 + (z_1(t) - z_2(t))^2} $$
where $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ are the coordinates of the two points in the euclidean space, respectively. I am trying to show (if possible) that the following holds in terms of the limit of $q(t)$ as time approaches infinity:
$$ \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\big(q(t)\big) = 0 $$
To do so, suppose that the following statements hold:
$$ |y_i(t)|<b_y, \ |z_i(t)|<b_z, |q(t)|<\bar{L}, \ i=1,2, \ \forall t\in [0 \ t_{max}) $$
where $b_y,b_z,\bar{L}$ are known positive constants and $t_{max}<\infty$. Moreover, suppose that the derivative of $q(t)$ is bounded, i.e., $\dot{q}(t) = \dot{d}(t)\in \mathcal{L}_{\infty} $, and more specifically the following holds:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\big(\dot{q}(t)\big)=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\big(\dot{d}(t)\big) = 0 $$
which means that the relative position between the two points converges to a constant value. In addition, suppose that regarding the $x_i$ coordinate, the following holds:
$$ x_i(0) < x_i(t) < x_i(0) + v_{max}\cdot t, \ i=1,2, \ \forall t\in [0 \ t_{max}) $$
where $v_{max}>0$ is the maximum velocity that can be reached by the two points and is considered to be known and constant. I have been trying to show this by using Barbalat's lemma or its variants, but so far in vain. At fist, I thought that since $\dot{q}_{12}(t)\in\mathcal{L}_\infty$ (and hence $q(t)$ is uniformly continuous), if I prove that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^tq(\tau)d\tau$ exist and is finite, then from Barbalat's lemma it is concluded that $lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}q(t) = 0$, but I did not manage to show it. I am wondering if there is another way around this or it just cannot be proven given the facts that I wrote and hold. And if not, is there maybe a complete different way to proceed and show it ?

You have vastly overcomplicated something simple. $d_{12}(t) = q_{12}(t) + L$. So by the basic results that $\lim (f+g) = (\lim f) + (\lim g)$ and $\lim L = L$, we get $\lim_{t\to\infty} d_{12}(t) = (\lim_{t\to\infty} q_{12}(t)) + \lim_{t\to\infty} L = 0 + L = L$.

You assumed that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}(q_{12}(t))=0$, but that is what I am trying to prove.

Really? Then why in the post did you say that what you were trying to prove is $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\big(q_{12}(t)\big) = 0 \implies \lim_{t\to\infty}\big(d_{12}(t)\big) = L?$$Where $\lim_{t\to\infty}\big(q_{12}(t)\big) = 0$ is the hypothesis, not the conclusion.

Ok, you are right. I edited it to avoid any misinterpretations.

But now it is unclear what it is that you do know. From the definition of $q$ (I am going to drop the 12 subscript, which has no importance at all to your question) we know that $$\lim_{t\to\infty} q(t) = 0 \iff \lim_{t\to\infty} d(t) = L$$ But you give no information about $d(t)$ that would indicate it converges to $L$. So all your argument has nothing to build from. What do you know about the behavior of $d(t)$?

Since $q(t)$ is bounded ($|q(t)|<\bar{L}$) and $L$ is a constant, it is obvious that $d(t)$ is bounded.

Where is $t$ on the rhs of $d_{12}(t)$? I am not used to this notation.

Did some editing to improve the question.

@Snoop - the question is about the distance between two paths through space parametrized by $t$ ("time").

Knowing that $d$ is bounded is not even sufficient to prove that $d(t)$ converges when $t \to \infty$, much less to the specific value $L$ by which it and $q$ differ. For example, it could be that $d(t) = 2+ \sin t$. Bounded, but not convergent. You've got to have some information about $d$ itself, or the paths $(x_i(t),y_i(t),z_i(t))$ that would allow you to deduce that $d \to L$.

The way you have this phrased is confusing. You start off saying just that you want to prove $\lim_{t\to\infty} q(t)= 0$, then to prove it, you start "supposing" things that have no particular reason to be true based on your set-up of the problem. In mathematics, you need to state the conditions under which a statement should be true first, not just add them willy-nilly to your proof. So instead of "I want to prove $q(t) \to 0$", you say "I want to prove that if $y_i, z_i, q$ are all bounded, and $\dot q \to 0$ and $0 \le x_i(t) \le x_i(0) + vt$, then $q(t) \to 0$."

But you can give up on that, because those conditions are not sufficient. $\dot q\to 0$ and $q$ bounded is sufficient to prove that $q$ converges to some value. However, it and the rest is not enough to say that the value is $0$.

Obviously, I have carried out some analysis (that I cannot post here) through which the statements of the question are proven to hold. I have not just "supposed" things and naively wrote them here. Anyway, I was just looking for some help to carry on, if possible, the analysis. Thanks for your time.
